# Template specializations with identical functions except for template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

How to take care of the repetitions below for the Object::func() definitions without using macros?

```
template <int N> struct Object {};

template <> struct Object<0> {
    // special stuff
    void func();
};

template <> struct Object<1> {
    // special stuff
    void func();
};

template <> struct Object<2> {
    // special stuff
    void func();
};

template <int N> struct Thing {};

void Object<0>::func() {
    Thing<0> a;
    // do stuff with a
}

void Object<1>::func() {
    Thing<1> a;
    // do exact same stuff with a
}

void Object<2>::func() {
    Thing<2> a;
    // do exact same stuff with a
}
```

Private inheritance, with the base having template int N?  Meta-template stuff?  CRTP?  I can't figure it out.  Note that

```
// special stuff
```

means that the template specializations are necessary--I'm just not showing how they are specialized.  I'm only showing the one function func() that are almost identical to all of them.

Comment: Note that you can explicitly specialize individual member functions of a class template. So maybe explicitly specializing the whole class template isn't necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, my solution is to use template template parameters to define your template class, I feel this is the way to avoid re-define common things over and over.

Below is the code that I just coded and tested in Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N> struct Thing { int x; Thing() : x(N) {}; };

template <int N, template<int N> class T> struct Object { void func(); };

template <int N, template<int N> class T> void Object<N, T>::func()
{
    T<N> a;
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
};

int main()
{
    Object<0, Thing> obj0;
    Object<11, Thing> obj11;
    Object<22, Thing> obj22;
    obj0.func();
    obj11.func();
    obj22.func();
    return 0;
}
```

This code will print:

0
11
22

Answer (score 1):

Using inheritance you can avoid specialization for the common code. How about:

```
template <int N> struct ObjectBase {
  void func();
};

template <int N> struct Thing {};

template <int N>
void ObjectBase<N>::func() {
    Thing<N> a;
    // do stuff with a
}

template <> struct Object<0>: private ObjectBase<0> {
    // special stuff
};

template <> struct Object<1>: private ObjectBase<1> {
    // special stuff
};

template <> struct Object<2>: private ObjectBase<2> {
    // special stuff
};
```

Comment: Possibly plus a using-declaration to make `func` public again. Or public inheritance.

Comment: @Suma to prevent/reduce code bloat - base class should be non template

Comment: @spin_eight It needs to be a template, because of the implementation of func.